# How can I convert bacterial species into phylum?

Tags: r, bigdata, analysis, dendrogram, phylogeny

I have a database presented in an excel table. There are only types of bacteria contained in different sites. How can I convert species to phyla using R? I have 4244 variables... [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fBXrA.png). I have no other information.

I tried to create a vector with names, compare them with the NCBI base, but nothing came of it. I couldn't find a solution on the forums :(

Comment: Please don't upload code, error messages, results or data as images for [these reasons](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557) - and [these](https://xkcd.com/2116/).

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow.  Can you give us some sample data (if you type, for example, `dput(head(mydata))` it will give you a code you can paste into your question containing the top few rows of `mydata`.